# JWT authentication and woocommerce keys are not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I am making a Vue js app which is connected to wocommerce and wordpress apis. I want my users to view products without login so I created consume key and consumer secret from woocomerce rest api and code like this

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;    
let auth = Buffer.from(process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_WC_KEY + ':' + process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_WC_SEC).toString('base64');
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Basic " + auth;

Vue.prototype.$http.get(config.WOO_API + '/products/categories')
        .then(
            (response) => {  
                console.log("category response", response);              
                return response.data;
            }
        )
```

Which works great. Now when I want my users to buy product after they login so for login I use [JWT plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/). When I login with api /WP-JSON/JWT-AUTH/V1/TOKEN and then I get token perfectly but after activating this plugin the public woocommerce APIs not working and throwing

```
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header",
    "message": "Authorization header malformed.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I understand woocomerce does work with jwt. When I pass both consumer key and secret as URL params it works but it has potential security risk.

So the summary is I want both JWT as well as woocommerce APIs to work with consumer key and secret without passing as URL params. Please let me know any work around.

Comment: You can't mix Authorization headers. You've got `Authorization: Basic ${user:password}` and JWT uses `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`. Are you switching the headers at some point?

Comment: I am also facing the same solution, did you find the solution